# How to query with a preference with LIKE?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-order-by

I have this query, using Postgres:

```
select *
from jobs
where short_name like '%GES.PAY%'
order by short_name;
```

which returns this result :

```
CRD.GES.PAY
GES.PAY
REL.GES.PAY
```

But how to have 'GES.PAY' the first line of the result , like that :

```
GES.PAY
CRD.GES.PAY
REL.GES.PAY
```

In other words I would like the exact name in first line, then the other cases. Is it possible to do that in one simple query, without using Levenshtein functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do conditional ordering:

```
order by 
   case when short_name = 'GES.PAY' then 0 else 1 end,
   short_name
```

In Postgres you can also express this as:

```
order by (short_name = 'GES.PAY')::int desc, short_name
```

Th latter works because `(condition)::int` returns `1` if the condition is fulfilled, else `0`.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend a trigram index and the trigram distance operator `<->`:

```
CREATE EXTENSION pg_trgm;
CREATE INDEX ON jobs USING gist (short_name gist_trgm_ops);

SELECT *
FROM jobs
WHERE short_name LIKE '%GES.PAY%'
ORDER BY short_name <-> 'GES.PAY';
```

Answer (score 0):

I am going to recommend storing by the location of the value in the string:

```
order by position('GES.PAY' in short_name)
```

Answer (score 0):

You've have several good answers, but I would like to throw out another one.

```
order by length(short_name)
```

The fewer letters short_name has, the fewer "extra" letters it can have over the number in the query.